# Twitter oAuth for clients websites

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, twitter-oauth

Do I need to create an oAuth application for every client website or can I create one and use my own? If I need to create one for each client, do I need to use their login information or can I just use mine and define their website in the application?

I'm trying to update all my clients to Twitter API 1.1, but am hoping has already gone through this with some advice! I used to use SimplePie in WordPress just to get Twitter statuses for clients or lists they created via ATOM in the v1 API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest method is to build a plugin that accepts each users authorisation credentials as a parameter. That way you'll only have the one code base which can be deployed across all your sites. The only potential hassle is getting your clients to authorise the app within their twitter accounts.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue. Some clients are more savvy than others, but this is the new reality with Twitter's API I suppose.

Comment: Yeah it is. Surely a service you could be paid to provide? I think that if you follow your client and authorise your own app you should be able to pull in their tweets.

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating an oAuth application for each client. Regardless of technical feasibility, these applications are not semantically identical and a user should not be unwittingly granting permission to all apps when they only meant to join one.

Comment: I wouldn't be using the application for authorizing tweets or anything. Just grabbing statuses and lists from the clients account and display something like the latest tweet on the homepage.